# ¿Como añado productos destacados en el archivo front-page del tema hijo de storefront de wordpress creado por mi?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theme

Quiero mostrar los productos destacados en front-page que cree en el tema hijo de storefront que hice, pero este código no funciona y no muestra nada en pantalla, y no entiendo muy bien el porque. el código lo saque de archive-product que viene hecho por defecto en woocommerce.

Aquí añado la cabecera a la web

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

Aquí quiero recorrer los productos y mostrarlos

```
if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) {

    
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );

    woocommerce_product_loop_start();

    if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();

            
            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        }
    }

    woocommerce_product_loop_end();

    
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
} else {
    
    do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
}
```

y aquí añado el footer.

```
<?php

get_footer();?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienes el shortcode [featured_products] que también puedes mostrar con do_shortcode()